# basic difference between OnSelectionChanged & OnDayRender of <asp:Calendar>

Tags: asp.net, calendar

What is the basic difference between `OnSelectionChanged & OnDayRender` of `<asp:Calendar>`

Instead of down-voting please try to answer my question as in future this will be useful for the new programmers like me.

thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`SelectionChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.selectionchanged.aspx) is an event which is triggered when **the User** has selected a day, a week, or an entire month by clicking the date selector controls.

[`DayRender`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.calendar.dayrender.aspx) is an event which is triggered when **ASP.NET** has rendered a day of the calendar on serverside.

> The DayRender event is raised when each date cell in the Calendar
>   control is created. You can control the contents and formatting of a
>   date cell when it is created by providing code in the event handler
>   for the DayRender event.